# Get current Cursor Position in Word (VSTO)

Tags: .net, ms-word, interop, ms-office

Is there a way for a Word Add-In to get the current cursor position within the document/on screen (e.g. to display my own control next to it)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the `Cursor.Position` property?