# Get the coordinates of mouse click after clicking a Button

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-on, mouseclick-event

I am developing an Addon for Ms-Word using c#, all I want is to get the coordinates of next click after a button is clicked.

Thanks in Advance.

```
//This is the Click

public void ClickRibbon(Office.IRibbonControl control){

     //After this, we have to read a next Click anywhere on the Form whose coordinates needs to be determined
}
```

Comment: can you show us code of what you tried?

Comment: see the edit bro @Neijwiert

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps..

```
    bool TrackFlag = false;

    public void ClickRibbon(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        TrackFlag = true;
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TrackFlag)
        {
            TrackFlag = false;
            int x = MousePosition.X;
            int y = MousePosition.Y;
            MessageBox.Show("Location (x,y) (" + x + "," + y + ")");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually I am working on MS-word Add-on, I don't know Microsoft have used as their `Form` `name` @lal

Comment: @ZaidAAmir Sorry, I thought you were using ribbon control in forms application. Have you tried the Cursor.Position property? [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031985/get-current-cursor-position-in-word-vsto)